# UWP C# Getting All Files From Selected Folder

Tags: c#, uwp, filepicker, argumentexception

I'm trying to get a list of all files in a selected folder using UWP and C#. I need to select a folder and display all audio files in that folder (including subfolders of the root folder

I have the following code:

```
        var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

        List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".ogg");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".flac");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".aiff");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".aac");

        QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate, fileTypeFilter);

        StorageFileQueryResult results = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> sortedFiles = await results.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (StorageFile item in sortedFiles)
        {
            AudioFilesLV.Items.Add(item.Path.ToString());
        }
```

However once I select the folder I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'
```

The folder I am selecting contains around 100 MP3 files

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a known issue with the CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate. Apparently you can only use CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate with the folders in the KnownFolders enumeration. If I change your code to use CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery it works.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f99384d9-5460-4fd4-8c70-5694e1370432/a-exception-is-happen-when-calling-getfilesasync-with-parameter-of-commonfilequeryorderbydate?forum=wpdevelop

You could just use an OrderBy as follows if they aren't coming back in date order:

```
foreach (StorageFile item in sortedFiles.OrderBy(a => a.DateCreated))
```

Comment: Andrew thank you very much, that seems to work great for root folders. Any idea how I can grab a list of subfolders which would grab files like this:

+ Main Folder
   + Sub Folder 1
      - SubFile1.mp3
   + Sub Folder 2
      - SubFile2.mp3
   - MyFile.mp3
   - MyFile2.mp3

Basically to get every file including subfolder files and then run a foreach? This isn't too important but sure would be nice :)

Thanks again :)

Comment: Thats a whole other story as you are getting into recursion. As a hint you need  to look at "folder.GetFoldersAsync()".

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'll take a look into that, like I say that's not a priority, my main priority was to grab a bunch of files either by selecting the files or folder so I'm happy for now, I can carry on with my app for now :D